# Sections in the margin and subsections on the same line as the section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'd like to write a document so that `\section` material shows up in the margin and so that `\subsection` material shows up on the same line as the `\section` in the margin (assuming there isn't anything else in between the `\section` and `\subsection` commands, of course).

Roughly, I'd like something that looks like this:

[image: desired output]

The following code (with the `\vspace` command uncommented) produces the output above.

However, this implementation seems a bit hacky since you have to put arbitrary `\vpsace`'s after each `\subsection` that isn't the first one beneath a `\section` command and after each `\subsection` that is the first `\subsection` in a `\section` but is preceded by other content.

What would be a better and more robust way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\section}
  {7pc}
  {1ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}
  {0pc}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\scshape\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {0pt}
  {-1.6\baselineskip}
  {0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{asdf}

\subsection*{qwerty}

\begin{itemize}
  \item{poiu}
\end{itemize}

%\vspace{1.6\baselineskip}
\subsection*{zxcv}

\begin{itemize}
  \item{lkjh}
\end{itemize}

\section*{mnbv}

lorem ipsum

%\vspace{1.6\baselineskip}
\subsection*{zqpm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly less hacky way. I've created a conditional using `etoolbox` to align subsections with sections if they immediately follow a section but not otherwise.

The only real hack here is that if you have a section which is *not* immediately followed by a subsection, you need to explicitly add a `\nosubsection` command after it.

Since you're not numbering sections or subsections I've just set `secnumdepth` to 0 rather than using `\section*` etc. which are not then necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlist{nosep}
\newbool{subsection}
\newcommand*{\nosubsection}{\global\boolfalse{subsection}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\global\booltrue{subsection}}

\titlespacing{\section}
  {1in}
  {1ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}
  {1em}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\ifbool{subsection}{\vspace{-1.6\baselineskip}\nosubsection}{}\large\scshape\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {0pt}
  {0pt}
  {0pt}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{item}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Subsection}

Some text

\begin{itemize}
  \item{item}
\end{itemize}

\section{Section}
\nosubsection
lorem ipsum

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]